# Unity not showing custom serialized class field in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I have a simple class that has the [System.Serializable] attribute on it and I am not sure why the field is not being displayed in the inspector.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Room
{
    [SerializeField] private Room m_parent;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2Int m_location;

    public Room parent => m_parent;
    public Vector2Int location => m_location;

    public Room(Vector2Int location, Room parent)
    {
        m_location = location;
        m_parent = parent;
    }
}
```

*Above code stripped down to highlight the field that is not being displayed.

Here is a stripped down script that uses the above class:

```
public class DungeonLayoutGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected List<Room> m_rooms;

    [SerializeField] protected int m_walkLength = 10;

    public byte[,] dungeonLayout { get; protected set; }

    private int m_walkCount = 0;

    private List<Vector2Int> SquareDirections = new List<Vector2Int>
    {
        new Vector2Int(1, 0),  // East
        new Vector2Int(-1, 0), // West
        new Vector2Int(0, 1),  // North
        new Vector2Int(0, -1), // South
    };

    private void Start()
    {
        m_rooms = new List<Room>();
        Generate(0, 0, null);
    }

    private void Generate(int x, int y, Room parent)
    {
        // Exit Conditions:
        if (m_walkLength > 0 && m_walkCount >= m_walkLength) { return; }
        if(CountSquareNeighbors(x, y, (byte)MapPart.Empty) >= 2) { return; }

        // Set current location:
        dungeonLayout[x, y] = (byte)MapPart.Empty; // Enum defined in another class.
        Room room = new Room(new Vector2Int(x, y), parent);
        m_rooms.Add(room);
        parent = room;
        
        // Increment Counter if we are counting walkLength:
        m_walkCount++;

        // Bail, We have generated enough rooms:
        if (m_walkCount >= 10) { return; }

        // Randomize our directions:
        SquareDirections.Shuffle(); // Defined in Extensions.cs

        // Reccursive Calls:
        Generate(x + SquareDirections[0].x, y + SquareDirections[0].y, parent);
        Generate(x + SquareDirections[1].x, y + SquareDirections[1].y, parent);
        Generate(x + SquareDirections[2].x, y + SquareDirections[2].y, parent);
        Generate(x + SquareDirections[3].x, y + SquareDirections[3].y, parent);
    }
}
```

When I run the game, everything works as intended but the when I expand the m_rooms field in the inspector, I only see the Vector2Int and the m_parent field isn't being displayed.  I added some debug code to the constructor of the Room class, to make sure that only the first Room created has a null value for m_parent.  Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a nested `Room` .. unity would need to serialize an infinite amount of rooms to present this structure in the Inspector => they don't

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom editor script in order for unity to be able to draw it in the inspector. Right now unity doesn't know how to show it in the inspector window. You can find a few tutorials on youtube about how to write editor scripts.

Comment: So Unity knows how to draw the Collection of Rooms but it needs to know how to draw the reference to each of internal Room references?

Comment: No. Unity does not know how to draw custom classes. You should specify it using override void ongui via editor script.